# Core Data: Fetch dictionaries grouped by multiple attributes

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data

I have an NSManagedObject subclass **Entry** with properties **type** (int) and **date** (NSDate). Right now I use the following code to get entries for the current date grouped by type.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entry"];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"type"];
NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:@[keyPathExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"entryCountByType"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:countExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger64AttributeType];

[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"type",expressionDescription]];
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"type"]];

[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@", [NSDate date]]];

NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [defaultManagedObjectContext() executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Results for a day with 1 entry of type 3 and 1 entry of type 5 are:

```
<_PFArray 0x15e05b50>(
{
    entryCountByType = 1;
    type = 3;
},
{
    entryCountByType = 1;
    type = 5;
}
)
```

I want to fetch without a date predicate at all and have counts for each type listed by date like so (where 1 day has 2 of type 1 and 1 of type 2, and another day has 3 of type 1 and 2 of type 2):

```
(
{
    date = 6/4/14 00:00:00;
    type1 = 2;
    type2 = 1;
},
{
    date = 6/5/14 00:00:00;
    type1 = 3;
    type2 = 2;
}
)
```

Is this possible in the way I'm thinking, that is, with a single fetch request? Doing a fetch for each day individually (about 30 sequential fetches) is really slowing down my app. I've tried adding @"date" to propertiesToGroupBy (after removing the date predicate, of course) but all that does is return a similar result to the first output, just with a date param thrown in so that each type for a day is split out into separate dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing "day" and "date". `NSDate` is accurate down to the millisecond, so you will likely have only unique dates. You cannot group by a date range.

One way is to store the day as a transient property. The scheme does not matter, but one possibility is e.g. `year * 10000 + month * 100 + day`.

If you want to dispense with the `NSExpression`s you could just use a method `day` in your entity that returns a day string (with `NSDateFormatter`) and use a `NSFetchedResultsController`  with `day` as the `sectionNameKeyPath` to display the grouped data.

Comment: I already worked around this by using NSDateComponents to keep only day/month/year for all NSDates but thanks for the input

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. You could still up-vote this answer to show appreciation for the effort because it explains the mechanics accurately.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote up, go figure.

Comment: In that case, you can always *accept* it as this answer captures your solution as well (substituting `NSDate` with your own data scheme).

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem though, sorry, as I can still have multiple entries per day and I need to get a total count for all on a particular day.

Comment: Yes it does. With a predicate for a particular day you can call `[fetchedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].count;`

Comment: That gets me a single day. If you look at my third block, I want a dict for each day on a single request.